# Sql agent job last run status

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have N jobs with M steps in each, that could change any time(Add/delete some steps). Jobs have different schedule to run. I want a query to get last run status, job id, job name of each job. Is it right way to do this scenario by `(Job outcome)` ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is the query I use (a little tuned) to check job status. This variation will select the last `job outcome` for each job.

```
SELECT
    JobName = J.name,
    H.*
FROM
    msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS J
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1
            JobName = J.name,
            StepNumber = T.step_id,
            StepName = T.step_name,
            StepStatus = CASE T.run_status
                WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed'
                WHEN 1 THEN 'Succeeded'
                WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry'
                WHEN 3 THEN 'Canceled'
                ELSE 'Running' END,
            ExecutedAt = msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(T.run_date, T.run_time),
            ExecutingHours = ((T.run_duration/10000 * 3600 + (T.run_duration/100) % 100 * 60 + T.run_duration % 100 + 31 ) / 60) / 60,
            ExecutingMinutes = ((T.run_duration/10000 * 3600 + (T.run_duration/100) % 100 * 60 + T.run_duration % 100 + 31 ) / 60) % 60,
            Message = T.message
        FROM
            msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory AS T
        WHERE
            T.job_id = J.job_id
        ORDER BY
            T.instance_id DESC) AS H
ORDER BY
    J.name
```

If you change the `TOP 1` for `TOP 2`, then you will also see the last step executed, aside from the `job outcome`.

Answer (score 5):

You can not get everything in a single query and need more research. For e.g., to know Job execution information you can try the following query.

```
SELECT 
    [sJOB].[job_id] AS [JobID]
    , [sJOB].[name] AS [JobName]
    , CASE 
        WHEN [sJOBH].[run_date] IS NULL OR [sJOBH].[run_time] IS NULL THEN NULL
        ELSE CAST(
                CAST([sJOBH].[run_date] AS CHAR(8))
                + ' ' 
                + STUFF(
                    STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([sJOBH].[run_time] AS VARCHAR(6)),  6)
                        , 3, 0, ':')
                    , 6, 0, ':')
                AS DATETIME)
      END AS [LastRunDateTime]
    , CASE [sJOBH].[run_status]
        WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed'
        WHEN 1 THEN 'Succeeded'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Canceled'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Running' -- In Progress
      END AS [LastRunStatus]
    , STUFF(
            STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([sJOBH].[run_duration] AS VARCHAR(6)),  6)
                , 3, 0, ':')
            , 6, 0, ':') 
        AS [LastRunDuration (HH:MM:SS)]
    , [sJOBH].[message] AS [LastRunStatusMessage]
    , CASE [sJOBSCH].[NextRunDate]
        WHEN 0 THEN NULL
        ELSE CAST(
                CAST([sJOBSCH].[NextRunDate] AS CHAR(8))
                + ' ' 
                + STUFF(
                    STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST([sJOBSCH].[NextRunTime] AS VARCHAR(6)),  6)
                        , 3, 0, ':')
                    , 6, 0, ':')
                AS DATETIME)
      END AS [NextRunDateTime]
FROM 
    [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobs] AS [sJOB]
    LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT
                    [job_id]
                    , MIN([next_run_date]) AS [NextRunDate]
                    , MIN([next_run_time]) AS [NextRunTime]
                FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobschedules]
                GROUP BY [job_id]
            ) AS [sJOBSCH]
        ON [sJOB].[job_id] = [sJOBSCH].[job_id]
    LEFT JOIN (
                SELECT 
                    [job_id]
                    , [run_date]
                    , [run_time]
                    , [run_status]
                    , [run_duration]
                    , [message]
                    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                                            PARTITION BY [job_id] 
                                            ORDER BY [run_date] DESC, [run_time] DESC
                      ) AS RowNumber
                FROM [msdb].[dbo].[sysjobhistory]
                WHERE [step_id] = 0
            ) AS [sJOBH]
        ON [sJOB].[job_id] = [sJOBH].[job_id]
        AND [sJOBH].[RowNumber] = 1
ORDER BY [JobName]
```

You can get and learn in details - [Here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2561/querying-sql-server-agent-job-information/) and [Here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2561/querying-sql-server-agent-job-information/)