# How to stop a SQL Agent job (running on an hourly schedule) to stop executing once it is successful

Tags: sql, sql-server, job-scheduling

I have a SQL Agent job that runs on the 7th of each month on an hourly basis. I want to stop it from running further once it is successful.

For example, if the job is successful at 8:00 A.M, I dont want it to run any more untill the 7th of next month. Any scripts would be helpful for this.

I am working on trying to establish this rule through the use of MSDB sys.jobs and an idea that I have is to update the Enabled flag to a 0 once the run is complete. Once the 7th of next month hits, another job on the SQL Agent could go in an update the flag back to a 1 so it can be run. i

Comment: Is the job expected to fail? You could simply check the last run status in MSDB as the first job step and abort if successful (using dbo.sp_stop_job), see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54215008/sql-agent-job-last-run-status)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create a new first job-step and, using the answer provided in the question [sql-agent-job-last-run-status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54215008/sql-agent-job-last-run-status), you can check if the last execution succeeded.

You can then cancel the job from executing by using `exec msdb.dbo.sp_stop_job`

I use this method in an Availability group cluster (to check if SQL Agent is running on the primary for jobs the require it) and abort the job if not. It works well.

Comment: I dont think sysjobhistory holds a lot of historical data. I cant see this months successful runs in there.

Comment: You can configure how much history is kept in sql agent properties

Answer (score 0):

How about, create a table with a row for last successful run, populate it on a successful run.

Then first thing in the job, check that table, and if the last successful run is since the 7th, terminate.

Otherwise run the rest of the job.

Comment: Cant create new tables. This would be an overkill tbh.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I finally deployed was to add a step to the job that would disable it once all preceding steps succeeded. I added another job to the Agent that would go and enable this job on the 1st of each month so that they are ready to be executed. Just throwing this out so that someone else can benefit.